# Find which line has the highest Z value of a set of lines intersecting a polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-join

I've a dataset of polygons representing buildings and a dataset of polylines representing buildings. The dataset  with lines has a Z value for each line, the polygon dataset doesn't. There are several lines of different object types that make up a building, each with different z values at they're a different part of the building.

I want to find the one line with the highest Z value for each building so I can then transfer the Z attribute of the highest line to the polygon file and visualise the max height of all buildings in 2D. So far I've tried just doing a one to many spatial join of lines within a building polygon to each building polygon, choosing max on the Z attribute as a merge rule without luck. Any ideas for how this can be done?

[image: Polygons in gray, lines in red]

Comment: Can you explain what didn't work in your case ? Are your layers in the same projection? A spatial join should be the correct way to do it, see example here: https://i.imgur.com/tV8ZsFP.png

Comment: It worked doing this in ArcGIS desktop. I was working in ArcGIS Pro and the options for spatial join are different. Doesn't seem to be an option for choosing how all attributes are summarised.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in this way:

1. Assign all polygons a unique `building_id`
2. Do a **Spatial Join** so each polyline is assigned the `building_id` it's associated with
3. In the new `sj_polyline` table, **Summarize** on the `building_id` and chose the `Z attribute` to perform **Statistics** on with the `"Maximum"` **Statistic Type**
4. **Join** the new `summarize_sj_polyline` table to your building polygon table to associate the maximum Z value from all associated polylines the corresponding building feature